# Is Интернационализм a French loanword?

Tags: этимология, заимствования

It obviously seems to have a Latin etymology, but I wonder if it came into  Russian from French.

Comment: yes, and it's quite easy to google it

Answer (score 2):

The word originates from Latin roots *inter*(между) plus *national*(nation)(национальный,народный) and appeared in Russian as a loan word from French at the beginning of the 20 th century(according to Etymological Dictionary of the Russian Language ).

Comment: Also it was popularized by the name of this anthem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Internationale